# SVD with gensim::LsiModel using a table containing -inf

Tags: gensim, svd

I have created a table of dimensions vocabulary*vocabulary using a text document and the npmi-scorer implemented within gensim:

```
def npmi_scorer(worda_count, wordb_count, bigram_count, len_vocab, min_count, corpus_word_count):
 if bigram_count >= min_count:
        corpus_word_count = float(corpus_word_count)
        pa = worda_count / corpus_word_count
        pb = wordb_count / corpus_word_count
        pab = bigram_count / corpus_word_count
        try:
            return log(pab / (pa * pb)) / -log(pab)
        except ValueError:  # some of the counts were zero => never a phrase
            return NEGATIVE_INFINITY
    else:
        # Return -infinity to make sure that no phrases will be created
        # from bigrams less frequent than min_count.
        return NEGATIVE_INFINITY
```

This returns -inf when count == 0 or when minCount is not met.

I would like to convert this to a 300-dimensional model using LsiModels implemented within gensim. LsiModels, however, does not accept -inf as entry. Is there a way how I can feed my npmi table with the -infs to LsiModels?
Or is there another way how to perform SVD on my table (preferably using gensim)?

I would ideally have something like:

```
corpus_sparse = sp.csr_matrix(npmi_table)
id2word = dict(enumerate(vocabulary.index.tolist()))

model = LsiModel(corpus_sparse, id2word=id2word, num_topics=10)
```

without running

```
npmi_table = np.nan_to_num(npmi_table, nan=0.0, posinf=None, neginf=-1e9)
```

first.

Thanks